# Auto-fill empty coordinates and smooth data with geom_raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, density-plot, geom-raster

Code:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(dat$x, dat$y)) + 
  xlim(-3,3) + 
  ylim(-5,5) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = dat$density),
              hjust = 0, vjust = 0, interpolate = TRUE, alpha =1)
```

Data:

```
x  y    density
1  -1  1 0.07589831
2   2  1 0.01999884
3   1  0 0.14752616
4  -1  0 0.10468884
5  -1  1 0.07589831
6  -1  0 0.10468884
7  -2  0 0.05619694
8   1  0 0.14752616
9  -2  1 0.05072076
10  1  0 0.14752616
11  1 -1 0.04915273
12 -2 -1 0.01330193
13 -1  1 0.07589831
14 -1  0 0.10468884
15  0  0 0.14332413
16  1 -1 0.04915273
17  0  0 0.14332413
18  0  0 0.14332413
19  3  0 0.03155999
20 -2  1 0.05072076
21  0  1 0.07323680
22  2 -1 0.03560643
23  0  0 0.14332413
24 -1  0 0.10468884
25  1  0 0.14752616
26  2  0 0.09192561
27  0  1 0.07323680
28  0  1 0.07323680
29 -3  1 0.03381405
30  0 -1 0.04760234
31  0  1 0.07323680
32 -1  1 0.07589831
33  1  2 0.01242018
34 -3  2 0.02415452
35  1  0 0.14752616
36 -3  2 0.02415452
37  0  0 0.14332413
38  0 -1 0.04760234
39  0  0 0.14332413
40  0  0 0.14332413
41 -2  0 0.05619694
42 -3  1 0.03381405
43 -1  0 0.10468884
44  2 -1 0.03560643
45  2  0 0.09192561
46  1  1 0.04103001
47  1  0 0.14752616
48  0 -1 0.04760234
49  1  0 0.14752616
50  1  0 0.14752616
51  2  0 0.09192561
52 -2  0 0.05619694
53  2  0 0.09192561
```

[image: dat]

I plotted x & y from data frame dat. How can I smooth the `geom_raster` to look almost fluid? I've added interpolate, but the plot still looks boxy? I would also like to fill in the empty spaces with the least dense color. Thank you!!

Comment: Filling the empty spaces has to be done at the level of your data. You would need to build an empty grid and set the known values. This is because interpolate needs something to work from.

Comment: As for the "boxy" aspect, this has to do with your graphic output. When I execute your code, the picture I get is indeed "smooth".